# Field of definition of a polynomial ideal which is preserved under a Galois action

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, galois-extensions, affine-varieties

Let $k$ be a perfect field and $\bar{k}$ its algebraic closure. Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $Gal(\bar{k}/k)$ of finite index. Let $L$ be the subfield of $\bar{k}$ of all elements which are fixed under the action of $H$. Then $L/k$ is a finite Galois extension.

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\bar{k}[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ such that $\sigma I=I$ for every $\sigma\in H$. Is it then true that $I$ is generated as an ideal of $\bar{k}[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ by $I\cap L[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$?

(in other words, is $I$ generated by polynomials over $L$?)

There's relevant information in [What is the field of definition of an invariant ideal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524465/what-is-the-field-of-definition-of-an-invariant-ideal) , but the answers there either reference to an old book or use nonabelian cohomology. I'm looking for a more accessible proof, and hopefully not just a reference, but a proof or at least an overview of one.

**Special case:** Let $X$ be an affine subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^n_{\bar{k}}$ defined by polynomials over $k$ such that each of its geometric components is mapped onto itself under the action of $H$. Is it then true that each component is defined by polynomials over $L$? This is my main interest.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! The following link might be of use https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisdescent.pdf

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is useful. Theorem 4.2 there says that under my assumptions, the Galois group acts on $I$, then it uses an affirmative answer to a special case of my question where the variety is a vector space, applies this to $I$ as a vector space, and notes that this also gives a solution to the original question (with $I$ thought of as an ideal).